# Capture Token Metadata for Newly Created ERC-721 Contracts

Tags: etherscan, erc-721, meta-data

I feel this shouldn't be a super difficult task, but I may be underestimating it. If anyone could put me on the right path to begin, I should be able to take it from there.

The part that is confusing me at the moment is where the data is actually stored. The token identifier I imagine is it's own txn seperate from the contract creation. The contract name is also a point of interest, and I assume that it's not actually on the txn, but instead is just metadata input through etherscan?

The use case in this situation would be to log any new ERC-721 contracts that have been created in the past n days and search for keywords either in the contract name or token identifier.

Thank you, and please let me know if I can answer any questions to make this question make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recognize if any contract is an ERC-721 contract by using ERC-165 introspection.

This is explained in the specifications respectively:

- https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721
- https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-165

What you're asking about is the easy part.

Now the hard part is running your node, dealing with syncing issues and recognizing all the new contracts that are created on chain.